# "mapper_parsing_exception" error in postman

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

i'm using postman to communicate with elastic search server and i am receiving an error in postman when i am trying to connect with my elastic search server. Where could i have gone wrong?
Here is my code.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "contact_email": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "image": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "post_id": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "state_province": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i've tried communicating with my server but i keep receiving this error

```
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [post : {properties={country={type=text}, image={type=text}, post_id={type=text}, city={type=text}, description={type=text}, state_province={type=text}, title={type=text}, contact_email={type=text}}}]"
            }
```

Comment: Can you post more details about what you're doing please? What request are you sending? Is this to a specific endpoint? Where have you put that `code` in Postman. That error is coming from the endpoint not Postman, it's just being displayed in the app.

Comment: i am sending a request to my firebase server  where elastic search has been deployed and  the properties like city,contact email..... are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using elasticsearch version 7.0. Since elasticsearch no more support more than one mapping type per index, mapping name is no more required and should not be provided in this version.
Remove the mapping name `post` from the json input. Use as below:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "city": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "contact_email": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "country": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "image": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "post_id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "state_province": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: On the same about mapping type, am receiving this error        StatusCodeError: 400 - {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [posts] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, -LcVpBay0SLV3c6fnpgt]"}],

Comment: When do you get this error? Are you trying to update mapping?

Comment: No i have not tryed to update mapping. I have created and index function using nodejs and deployed it into firebase.The error occurrs in the firebase logs. I get the error when trying to test whether my function is working and it seems like the error refers me back to mapping. Is it possible that i may have to update mapping and if so how do i update mapping?

Comment: Can you post a separate question for the same with details of what you are trying to achieve and related code snippet. That will give a better understanding.