# I'm trying to post some data using postman and its giving me the error below

Tags: elasticsearch

Response received from elastic when trying to post x

```
{
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [house_locations : {properties={image={type=text}, post_id={type=text}, city={type=text}, user_id={type=text}, description={type=text}, state_province={type=text}, house_type={type=text}, title={type=text}, contact_email={type=text}}}]"
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the request you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["mapper\_parsing\_exception" error in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664038/mapper-parsing-exception-error-in-postman)